# What happened when ajax call Action and nothing happen

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass values to Controller for making a PDF.
I create a Var Filter with many data, and other variable with respective necessesary.

When I call Controller, nothing happen.
I'm NOT an expert in MVC and AJAX.
Can someone help me?

View JavaScript:

```
function GeneratePdfUsuarios() {
        var Filter = {
            Nombre: $("#F_Nombre").val(),
            Cargo: $("#F_Cargo").val(),
            Iniciales: $("#F_Iniciales").val(),
            UserName: $("#F_Usuario").val(),
            Email: $("#F_Correo").val(),
            Enabled: $("#EstadosList").val(),
            BirthDay_Since: $("#F_Fecha_Desde").val(),
            BirthDay_to: $("#F_Fecha_Hasta").val(),
            RoleName: $("#RolesList").val(),
            Sucursal: $("#SucursalesList").val()
        };
        var Title = "Usuarios";
        var Description = "Listado de usuarios del sistema";
        GeneratePdfList(1, Filter, Title, Description);
    }

function GeneratePdfList(pDataCoType, pFilter, pTitle, pDescription) {
      var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
      var _data = {
            DataCoType: pDataCoType //A number for Enumeration
          , Filter: pFilter   //An Object with Data
          , Title : pTitle    // Title for PDF
          , Description: pDescription // Simple Description fpr Pdf
          , __RequestVerificationToken: token
    };

    //ShowLoading();
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        ,dataType: 'json',
        url: "/Utility/GeneratePdfList",
        type: 'POST',
          data: _data,//JSON.stringify({ '_data': _data }),
          success: function (data) {
              if (data['success']) {
                  swal("Info","Entro","success");
                  //window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Usuarios", "Account")";

              } else {
                  swal({
                      title: "Error!",
                      text: data['error'] + " !",
                      type: "warning",
                      timer: 100500,
                      allowOutsideClick: false,
                      allowEscapeKey: false,
                      showConfirmButton: true

                  });
                  swal("Peligro","Algo Fallo en el controlador "+e.Message,"warning");
                  //var message = document.createTextNode(data['error']);
                  //var p = $('#genericError')
                  //p.empty();
                  //p.append(message);
              }
          },
          error: function () {
              swal("Peligro", "Failed " + e.Message, "warning");
          }
    });

}
```

ActionResult in Controller:

[image: ActionResult in Controller]

Comment: You are sending 5 parameters instead of 4 to the controller's action. Try to send the token into the request context header or something like that. Your controller's action is expecting 4 parameters.

Comment: I remove token and the same happen. In others actions always send token without parameter

Comment: Then I can just assume that the problem lies in the type of objects that you are sending...model binder cannot bind them. Try create and use custom model binder.

Comment: I remove Object and Enumerator and test with Title and Description and happen the same problem